# Find command returns wrong files

Tags: shell, find

I'm trying to find files in a folder using find command which are a day older than the day on which the command is run.. I use the following command:

```
FILES_dcn=($(find  $dir_dcn -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap" -mtime +1 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lt | tail -15 | awk '{print $9}'))
```

But the output seems to be like :

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097664 Mar 16 01:58 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_16_01_58_00_438.pcap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    27935978 Mar 17 10:00 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_16_18_29_18_983.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097296 Mar 17 10:02 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_17_10_02_00_335.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097192 Mar 17 10:02 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_17_10_02_49_476.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097936 Mar 17 10:07 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_17_10_06_59_326.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097464 Mar 17 10:10 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_17_10_10_00_407.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097232 Mar 17 10:13 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_17_10_13_48_603.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk   426800 Mar 17 10:14 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_17_10_13_58_428.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097544 Mar 17 10:14 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_17_10_14_10_259.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097600 Mar 17 10:14 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_17_10_14_49_609.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097472 Mar 17 10:17 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_17_10_16_59_503.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097696 Mar 17 10:17 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_17_10_17_48_698.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2098048 Mar 17 10:18 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_17_10_18_29_981.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097352 Mar 17 10:20 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_17_10_20_10_320.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097416 Mar 17 10:20 /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/dcn_2014_03_17_10_20_49_703.pcap
```

Its should have been

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097296 2014-03-17 10:02 dcn_2014_03_17_10_02_00_335.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk   443736 2014-03-17 10:02 dcn_2014_03_17_10_01_58_254.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2098136 2014-03-17 10:01 dcn_2014_03_17_10_01_48_427.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097456 2014-03-17 10:01 dcn_2014_03_17_10_01_38_622.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097480 2014-03-17 10:01 dcn_2014_03_17_10_01_28_773.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097184 2014-03-17 10:01 dcn_2014_03_17_10_01_18_966.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097184 2014-03-17 10:01 dcn_2014_03_17_10_01_09_127.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097272 2014-03-17 10:01 dcn_2014_03_17_10_00_59_280.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097896 2014-03-17 10:00 dcn_2014_03_17_10_00_49_462.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097376 2014-03-17 10:00 dcn_2014_03_17_10_00_39_653.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097344 2014-03-17 10:00 dcn_2014_03_17_10_00_29_816.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097656 2014-03-17 10:00 dcn_2014_03_17_10_00_19_977.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097232 2014-03-17 10:00 dcn_2014_03_17_10_00_10_172.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk  2097656 2014-03-17 10:00 dcn_2014_03_17_10_00_00_323.pcap
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nethawk nethawk   435544 2014-03-17 10:00 dcn_2014_03_17_09_59_58_280.pcap
```

And the current time Fri Mar 21 16:10:42 UTC 2014. Why is this happening ?  The files are stored in a samba share drive.

Comment: A day older than what?

Comment: Day older than today. Isn't that mtime +1 does? Or did I get that wrong?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to find files that were last modified exactly 24 hours ago (not more or less). Is that correct?

Comment: @NigelNquande Yes, you are absolutely correct.

Comment: Oh.. Ok.. can you please suggest me a solution ?

Comment: As far as I can make out from http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/03/10-find-command-in-unix-examples-basic.html, you should be using `-mtime 1` (exactly 1 day) or `-mtime +1` (1 day or more).

Comment: @Nigel, using `mtime 1` in the above example would find files created at *exactly* `Fri Mar 20 16:10:42 UTC 2014`. None of the files in the expected output have this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using will find files older than 24 hours. For your current time of `Fri Mar 21 16:10:42 UTC 2014`, this would be files modified before `Fri Mar 20 16:10:42 UTC 2014`. However from your question it seems that you want files modified before `Fri Mar 21 00:00:00 UTC 2014`.

The way to do this is to create a temporary file and change the modification time to midnight that day (simply specify the date only). The `find` command can then compare to this file. This will work on Linux:

```
time_file=$(mktemp)
touch -d "$(date +%F)" "$time_file"
find  $dir_dcn -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap" ! -newer "$time_file" \
  -exec ls -lt {} + |
  tail -15 |
  awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
rm "$time_file"
```

Note the `+%F` is not POSIX, here you would have to use `+%Y-%m-%d` (also `mktemp` is no POSIX, but can be found on most Unix-like systems). Note also the differences in the time format of the output you have posted. In the first the filename is field 9, in the second field 8. This will vary depending on how locale related environment variables are set. I have got around this by making `awk` print the last field rather than a specific field number. This will work as long as there are no spaces etc in the filenames.

#### Update

Actually looking more carefully at your intended vs expected output, it looks more like what has happened is that there have been so many files that `xargs` has done more than one run of `ls`. This would prevent the files from being sorted properly. Since the files are date stamped, it the simplest thing to do is to pipe to `sort` instead of using `ls`.

```
time_file=$(mktemp)
touch -d "$(date +%F)" "$time_file"
find  $dir_dcn -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap" ! -newer "$time_file" |
  sort |
  tail -15
rm "$time_file"
```

Comment: Thanks your answer. Can you please tell me one thing, as I'm running this script every 10 minutes everyday , how would I make this "$(date +%F)" , the date I need?

Comment: @Jishnu, I don't understand what you are asking. On a current Linux system, `"$(data +%F)"` will be the date that you need.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I got a bit confused.

Comment: If I want to modify the time as say 5 days, would  date +%F -d "$DATE - 5 day"  be correct way to do it?

Comment: With GNU `date` you can do `date -d "-5 days" +%F` or `date -d "5 days ago" +%F`.

Comment: @JishnuUNair, forgot to @ you on my last comment.

Answer (score 5):

The `find` command will display the desired results if all of it's conditions are true.  If not, the output will be unexpected, making it appear that it is not working.

To `find` the files that are exactly 24 hours old, `-mtime 1` is required.  However, if there are no files meeting this condition, `ls -lt` will list all the files in the `find` path.

Similarly, if you search for `-name "*nopcap"` but there are no files ending with `nopcap`, all files in the `find` path will be displayed.

According to the `find` man page:

> > ```
> >   Numeric arguments can be specified as
> >
> >   +n     for greater than n,
> >
> >   -n     for less than n,
> >
> >   n      for exactly n.
> > ```
> >
> > ...
> >
> > ```
> >   -mtime n
> >             File’s  data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for -atime 
> >             to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file modification
> >             times.
> > ```